# how webpack loads jQuery?

Tags: webpack

The only configuration I've set related to jQuery loading is:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    $: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery'
})
```

In order to use it:

```
declare var jQuery: any;
```

I dont understand how webpack is able to load jQuery sources. It's magic for me.

Which's the processes webpack runs in order to get it?

I've installed it using `npm install jquery` but how webpack know where to pick it up?

I don't know if I've explained so well.

Comment: Webpack looks inside the project's `node_modules` folder for a folder named `jquery` and follows it's declarations (package.json).

Comment: And what about raw javascript libraries are only distributed by cdn like (stripe - [https://js.stripe.com/v2/](https://js.stripe.com/v2/))? How it is loaded?

Comment: External libraries for example a CDN aren't a webpack task, they should be loaded at runtime with something like `scriptjs`.

Comment: Thanks @cirix. I've read this [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#externals). It's talking a bit about external concept. Could you tell me your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

The `ProvidePlugin` takes an object where each key is the name of a variable and the value is the name of a module. When webpack sees a free variable, that is a variable that has not been declared before, which is the case when it's expected to be a global variable, it adds a `require` statement with the configured module. For example with `$: 'jquery'` when it sees the global `$` being used, it will add the following statement at the top of the module:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

That is the same as if you had done it manually in the file and it follows the same rules for resolving the module as with any other import you're using. In this case it uses the one in `node_modules`.

For more information see [Shimming](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#provideplugin) and [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/).

The `declare var jQuery: any;` has nothing to do with webpack, and is only needed to tell TypeScript what type the jQuery variable has.